# Select multiple value in ListBox using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why "SelectedValue" selects only the first value in my multiple selection mode ?

```
<dt>Tags:</dt><dd>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListTag" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTag" DataTextField="tag_name" 
    DataValueField="tag_id">
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceTag" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_cc %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</dd>
```

> ```
> ListTag.SelectedValue = "Tag1"; <-- only this is selects
> ListTag.SelectedValue = "Tag2";
> ```

Comment: `SelectedValue` represents only single value that's why you get first selected value. If you want to get all the selected value you need to iterate thru the items of list and check Selected property of each item and get the Value of it if it's true.

Answer (score 2):

in your asp page you have this.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListTag"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="250px">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-1" Value="1">Tag - 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-2" Value="2">Tag - 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-3" Value="3">Tag - 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-4" Value="4">Tag - 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-5" Value="5">Tag - 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-6" Value="6">Tag - 6</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-7" Value="7">Tag - 7</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-8" Value="8">Tag - 8</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-9" Value="9">Tag - 9</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Tag-10" Value="10">Tag - 10</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

then in your **cs(Code Behind)** in the event that you want you have this.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < lsBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = lsBox.Items[i];
            string[] selectecvalues = new string[] { "1", "3", "6", "9" };

            if (selectecvalues.Contains(item.Value)) // or item.Text  if you like
            {
                lsBox.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

that will result in Tags 1,3,6,9 selectd

Comment: It does not work. I have to programmatically select several tags. There is no need to check is some options are selected.

Comment: I dont't have method,,SetSelected'' in ListTag

Comment: I have  ListTag.Items.Count = 0  so I can't looping for this, but I have options tags with multiple choices

Comment: @Daniel you need to load the data before, called the looping

Comment: Thanks  @ThaNet  I I forgot to add   ListTag.DataBind();  :)